# Running WinSCP command from Python

Tags: python, command-line, sftp, winscp

I have created the following command file with name `submitCmd.txt`:

```
open myname@ftpclients.myserve.com -privatekey=C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\uploader\mykey.ppk
put C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\uploader\files2Upload\myFile.xlsx /mnt/data/myFolder/
close
exit
```

When I run the above script from command line as:

```
winscp.com /script=C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\uploader\submitCmd.txt
```

It runs successfully.

However, when I try the following in python:

```
cmdFile = r'C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\uploader\submitCmd.txt'
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["winscp.com", "/script=", cmdFile], shell=True)
```

I get the error:

```
Searching for host...
Host "C" does not exist.
winscp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command will run WinSCP like this:

```
winscp.com /script= C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\uploader\submitCmd.txt
```

What is an invalid syntax. There cannot be the space after the `/script=`.

This should work:

```
subprocess.run(["winscp.com", "/script=" + cmdFile], shell=True)
```

---

If you want to avoid creating a script file, see: [From Python run WinSCP commands in console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56449699/850848).