# From Python run WinSCP commands in console

Tags: python, console, sftp, winscp, windows-console

I have to run a few commands of WinSCP from a Python class using subprocess.

The goal is to connect a local Windows machine and a Windows server with no FTP installed and download some files. This is what I tried

```
python    
proc = subprocess.Popen(['WinSCP.exe', '/console', '/WAIT',  user:password@ip:folder , '/WAIT','get' ,'*.txt'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

With this I get it to open the WinSCP console and connect to the server, but it doesn't execute the `get` command. Is the problem because the `get` is executed on the Windows console and not in the WinSCP console?

I also tried replacing `winscp.exe /console` for `winscp.com /command`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want do without generating a script file, you can use a code like this:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['WinSCP.com', '/ini=nul', '/command',
     'open ftp://user:password@example.com', 'get *.txt', 'exit'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):  # replace b'' with '' for Python 2
    print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

The code uses:

- [`/command` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) to specify [commands](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#commands) on WinSCP command-line;
- [`winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) instead of `winscp.exe`, as `winscp.com` is a console application, so its output can be [read by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18421757/850848).

---

Though using the array for the arguments won't work, if there are spaces in command arguments (like file names). Then you will have to format the complete command-line yourself. See [Python double quotes in subprocess.Popen aren't working when executing WinSCP scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65802754/850848).

Comment: This solution works excellent! Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

So when using the `/script` option you should specify a file containing the batch commands.

To specify all the commands on the command line as you're doing, use the `/command` option instead of `/script`.

Comment: That and use `winscp.com`, instead of `winscp.exe`.

Comment: I tried that change but didnt work. The change is ['WinSCP.com', '/command',  user:password@ip:folder,'get' ,'*.txt']

Comment: And also didnt get any message on the console