# Python double quotes in subprocess.Popen aren't working when executing WinSCP scripting

Tags: python, windows, whitespace, double-quotes, winscp

I am attempting to use the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454579 to upload files to a server with WinSCP from Python on Windows 10. The code looks like this:

```
import subprocess
path = r'C:\mp4s\Sci-Fi Light Flicker.mp4'

process = subprocess.Popen(
  ['C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com', '/ini=nul', '/command', 'option batch abort', 'option confirm off', 'open ftp://user:pass@ftp.website.com', f'put "{path}"', 'exit'],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
  print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

I get the output:

```
batch           abort
confirm         off
Connecting to ftp.website.com ...
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] user@ftp.website.com
File or folder '\C:\mp4s\Sci-Fi' does not exist.
System Error.  Code: 123.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Abort
```

Which tells me that the `put` command isn't properly handling the spaces in the filename. What do I need to change to get this to work? Removing the double quotes around the path gives me a different error (it thinks I'm trying to upload multiple files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can use an array to provide arguments to WinSCP. The [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) escapes double quotes in the arguments using backslash, what conflicts with [double double-quotes escaping](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax) expected by WinSCP.

You will have to format the WinSCP command-line on your own:

```
args =  "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com\" /ini=nul " + \
       f"/command \"open ftp://user:pass@ftp.website.com\" \"put \"\"{path}\"\"\" exit"
```

(note that I've omitted your [`option` commands](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option), as they are defaults anyway)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize Popen could take arguments like that. Works great. Although I prefer to use raw strings since it makes it a bit more readable: `r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /ini=nul ' + fr'/command "open ftp://user:pass@ftp.website.com" "put ""{path}""" exit'`