# Paramiko SSH connection timeout after 3 hours

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, timeout, paramiko, scp

I develop a Python two scripts to transfer lot of data (~120Go) on my vm, with Paramiko.
My vm is on OVH server.
First script transfert ~ 40Go, and the second script ~ 80Go.

Stack :

Python 3.9.1

Paramiko 2.7.2

SCP 0.13.3

On my both scripts, I use this function to setup SSH connection.

```
def connect():

    transport = paramiko.Transport((target_host, target_port))
    transport.connect(None, target_username, target_pwd)
    sftp_client = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    green_print("SSH connected")

    return sftp_client, transport
```

If I create one script which do the two transfer, I'm timeout after 3 hours.

With two distincts script which run in the same time, I'm timeout after 2h30 of transfer.

I already read many many many post on Paramiko, SSH connection, timeout parameter, ClientAliveInterval, etc... But nothing works.

After this time, I have this error
 `Connexion fermée par l'hôte distant` / `Connection closed by remote host`

Three functions of my script :

```
def connect():

    transport = paramiko.Transport((target_host, target_port))
    transport.connect(None, target_username, target_pwd)
    sftp_client = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    green_print("SSH connected")

    return sftp_client, transport


def transfert(sftp, vm, object_path):
    os.chdir(os.path.split(object_path)[0])
    parent = os.path.split(object_path)[1]

    try:
        sftp.mkdir(vm)
    except:
        pass

    for path, _, files in os.walk(parent):
        try:
            sftp.mkdir(os.path.join(vm, path))
        except:
            pass
        for filename in files:
            sftp.put(os.path.join(object_path, filename),
                     os.path.join(vm, path, filename))


def job():
    green_print("\nProcess start...")
    check_folder()

    folder = forfiles_method()
    vm, lidar, pos = name_path(folder)

    sftp, transport = connect()
    transfert(sftp, vm, pos)
    sftp.close()
    transport.close()
```

minimal reproducible example :

```
from paramiko.sftp_client import SFTPClient
import paramiko
import os

target_host = 'xx.xx.x.xxx'
target_port = 22
target_username = "xxxxxxx"
target_pwd = 'xxxxxx'

remote_path = "e:/x/"  # => on your vm
target_folder = '/folder1'  # => on your computer


def connect():

    transport = paramiko.Transport((target_host, target_port))
    transport.connect(None, target_username, target_pwd)
    sftp_client = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    return sftp_client, transport


def transfert(sftp, remote_path, object_path):
    os.chdir(os.path.split(object_path)[0])
    parent = os.path.split(object_path)[1]

    try:
        sftp.mkdir(remote_path)
    except:
        pass

    for path, _, files in os.walk(parent):
        try:
            sftp.mkdir(os.path.join(remote_path, path))
        except:
            pass
        for filename in files:
            sftp.put(os.path.join(object_path, filename),
                     os.path.join(remote_path, path, filename))


def job():
    sftp, transport = connect()
    transfert(sftp, remote_path, target_folder)
    sftp.close()
    transport.close()
```

The tree structure of my files, and I want to transfer only the "test" folder which contains more than 120GB.

folder / test

I'm new in Python dev.
If someone have a solution, I take it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution :

`subprocess.run(["winscp.com", "/script=" + cmdFile], shell=True)`

If winscp.com is not found like command, insert the path like : C:/Program Files (x86)/WinSCP/winscp.com

Write your commandes line in a txt file, here cmdFile.

Links, which can help you :

[Running WinSCP command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066584/running-winscp-command-from-python)

[From Python run WinSCP commands in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449699/from-python-run-winscp-commands-in-console)

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline